# Kindly please help my Jetta 4 tdi not starting after engine overhaul, showing the error codes below

Tags: starting, vw, diesel, jetta

[image]
My Jetta 4 tdi not starting showing those error codes

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I would have to assume with the second code, the solenoid is going to sit in the closed position so no fuel will flow if the circuit is open or short circuited to ground. My guess is, the solenoid did not reconnected during the rebuild process, so you might want to track that down.